# How to automatically switch to Edit Mode after creating a page?

Tags: 2013, development

When adding a new page to SharePoint (through Pages list) and clicking OK, the user is redirected to Pages list. How to force SharePoint to open that page in Edit Mode?

I've been thinking about adding a Response.Redirect statement in the ItemAdded Event Receiver but I'm not sure if it's the right attempt.

Comment: what's wrong in Response.Redirect? I guess it's fine.